# ImportError: cannot import name certs

Tags: python

Estou executando alguns exercícios que vou encontrando na internet. Um deles é para usar o [módulo `requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/)

Fiz a instalação do módulo em /site-packages, porém quando tento importá-lo, o `shell` me retorna a seguinte mensagem:

```
>>> import requests

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
import requests
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
from . import utils
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 24, in <module>
from . import certs
ImportError: cannot import name certs
```

Comment: Como você fez a instalação do módulo?

Comment: Fiz de duas formas.
Na primeira, baixei o zip do módulo e coloquei na pasta /site-packages. Utilizei a instrução >> python setup.py install.

A segunda forma foi usando easy_install.

Estou usando windows7

Comment: Qual é a versão do Python que você está usando? A biblioteca requests só suporta versões acima da Python 2.6. Talvez seja isso... Outro teste que você pode fazer é pegar a versão mais nova do requests no git: `git clone git://github.com/kennethreitz/requests.git`.

Comment: Estou usando a versão 2.7.6 em windows 7. A situação já está resolvida. Refiz a instalação do Python e peguei a versão mais nova do requests no git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema pode ser resolvido reinstalando o Python (versão 2.7.6), e posteriormente a biblioteca Requests, diretamente pelo git:

```
git clone git://github.com/kennethreitz/requests.git
cd requests
python setup.py install
```